# Adding dynamicly column on PyQt QTableView and sqlite DB

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple TableView drawn from sqlite database(ref LaBase)in code, with mainly 2 columns filled with datetime.I substract on every row datetime2 from datetime1 to get a time delta. The question is :
1/ how do I display the result i.e the time delta in a 3rd column and
2/ how do I insert the results in the database?
Relevant code:

```
class MainDialog(QDialog, TabView.Ui_Dialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    # appel de la classe du module dbessai
    self.LaBase = LaBase()
    self.model = QSqlTableModel()
    self.model.setTable("Contact")
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnRowChange)
    self.model.select()
    self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
    self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "pilot_1")
    self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "datetime1")
    self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "datetime2")
    self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Calcul")
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

def setdata(self):
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO Contact (pilot_1,datetime1,datetime2,total)" "VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
    query.bindValue(0, self.lineEdit_pilote.text())
    query.bindValue(1, self.dateTimeEdit.text())
    query.bindValue(2, self.dateTimeEdit_2.text())
    query.bindValue(3, self.get_date_diff()) #This line is wrong
    query.exec_()
    self.model.select()

def remove_row(self):
    index = self.tableView.currentIndex()
    deleteconf = QMessageBox.critical(self.parent(), "DELETE ROW", "REALLY DELETE", QMessageBox.Yes,
                                      QMessageBox.No)
    if deleteconf == QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.model.removeRow(index.row())
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.model.select()
        return
    else:
        return

def get_date_diff(self):
    quer = QSqlTableModel(self.model)
    quer.setTable("Contact")
    quer.select()
    i = 0
    while i < quer.rowCount():
        time1 = quer.record(i).value("datetime1")
        time2 = quer.record(i).value("datetime2")
        i += 1
        diff = datetime.strptime(time2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") - datetime.strptime(time1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        return diff

@pyqtSlot()
def on_calculer_clicked(self):
    self.get_date_diff()

@pyqtSlot()
def on_pushButton_4_clicked(self):
    self.setdata()

@pyqtSlot()
def on_Effacer_clicked(self):
    self.remove_row()
```

By simply converting `query.bindValue(3, self.get_date_diff())` to `query.bindValue(3, str(self.get_date_diff()))` I managed to get what I wanted but I get it only for the first row... I guess i need a for loop somewhere in method remove_row to get all the lines. Any idea?

Comment: You should use a `QProxyModel` to add the missing *Time Delta* column.

Comment: Store the dates as timestamps (i.e. floating point values), and do all the calculations using the [sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). That way, you can add the third column as part of the select statement, and format the dates in whatever way you like. I highly recommend that you install something like [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) so you can experiment with a live database and see how all the sqlite functions work.

Comment: Hi ekhumoro thanks for the reply.I already have sqlitebrowser. My problem is not that much the calculation but really more about how to save it in the DB once the calculation is done and then how to  dispay it...

Comment: You don't need to store anything. Just [set a query](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery) with the appropriate select statement, and the table will display the results automatically (i.e. exactly as it does in sqlitebrowser). You could also [create a view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) and then use that as the table for the model.